# Trying to check expire dates with today's date

Tags: c#

I am trying to highlight expiration dates when its within 21days of today's date, it seems to be working for the most part. However, it seems to be highlighting next years date also. so for example: Today 2/22/2017 , it is highlighting expire dates of 2/28/2017. But it is also highlighting 2/29/2018, which is a FULL year from now. How do I get it to also include year check. Right now its just days.

Code I am using below:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
var TwentyOneDays = expirationDate.AddDays(-21);

var TenDays = expirationDate.AddDays(-10);

if (now > TwentyOneDays && now < expirationDate)
{
     row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
     row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

     // .....
}
```

Comment: What date format is row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() returning? i.e. what does the date formatting in your document look like. Does it specify a year?

Comment: Check if `DateTime.Now < expirationDate ` returns true.

Comment: Just a hunch.  Try removing ToString() in row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()

Comment: date format mm/dd/yyyy. Tried with formatting dd/mm/yyyy too. same thing

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the if statement and check the values of `now`, `expirationDate` and `TwentyOneDays `

Comment: Ok added the breakpoint. errm. The values are

now 2/22/2017 1:02:52 PM
expirationDate 6/30/2017 12:00:00am
TwentyOneDays 6/9/2017 12:00:00am

Comment: And did it enter the the if block?

Comment: I figured it out. It was an issue with one of the if statements I am using with it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using TimeSpan to know the difference between two dates. e.g.

```
DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(21);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan diff = expirationDate - now;

int days = diff.Days; // This would give 20
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help/s you. if you are already set your desired expired date. then we will get today's date.

The code below will retrieve all your desired expired date to current date today.

```
private void getexpireddate()
{
try
{
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
connect.Open();
string sql="SELECT expireddate FROM data1 where date(date) = date(now())";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
da.Fill(ds);
datagrid.DataSource=ds;

}
catch(Exception ee)
{
Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual ActionResult Expire()
{       
    var TableName = Repository<TableName>.Find();           
    foreach (var item in TableName)
    {
            DateTime expirationDate = item.PMDate.AddDays(item.FeildDays);
            DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;            
            TimeSpan diff = expirationDate - Now;
            int days = diff.Days;  
            return View();
    };
```